# WSL2: can ping by FQDN but not by host

Tags: networking, ping, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

In WSL2, I can ping by FQDN:

```
$ ping host02.foo.org
PING host02.foo.org (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host02.foo.org (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=33.7 ms
```

but not by the host's name:

```
$ ping host02
ping: host02: Name or service not known
```

I can ping by either address in the host.

** edit **

I'm using Cisco AnyConnect to establish a VPN connection to the corporate network.

** /edit **

What's missing in WSL?

Comment: The DNS suffix, probably? Take a look at `/etc/resolv.conf`, does it contain a `search` line?

Comment: No.  Two `nameserver` lines for google's DNSs and two  `nameserver` lines for the corporate DNSs.

Comment: Are you sure a primary DNS suffix is properly set up _in Windows_? My WSL 1 inherits this (`search` entry). WSL 2 does not.

Comment: `host02` is another PC on the same corporate network, right?

Comment: Try `ping host02.local`.

Comment: @harrymc Worth a shot, but doubtful, I think.  I don't think mDNS is common in corporate networks, and at the very least it would only extend to the current broadcast domain, I believe.

Comment: `host02` is a server on the corporate network.  `ping host02.local` failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer:*

Try adding:

```
search foo.org
```

... to your manually-generated `/etc/resolv.conf

*More details:*

Without knowing your exact configuration (mostly the corporate network side), I'm making some educated guesses here ...

By default, WSL2 simply sets a single nameserver in its auto-generated `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver <Hyper-V virtual switch address>
```

The Hyper-V virtual switch is what proxies resolution from WSL2 to the Windows resolver.  So ultimately, it's (by default) the *Windows* resolver that handles that `ping host02` in a normal situation.

The Windows end-of-things gets the search suffix configured by either:

- DHCP
- or Group Policy Object

As long as *Windows* is resolving *on behalf of WSL2*, this works fine:

- You `ping host02`
- Linux gets the address of the nameserver from the auto-generated `/etc/resolv.conf`
- The nameserver address is the Hyper-V switch that is running a proxy resolver process
- The proxy resolver asks Windows to resolve `host02`
- (Probably skipping a few internal steps here, but ...) Windows appends its known search suffixes in order to see if they resolve.

But if you override your `/etc/resolv.conf` and take the Windows/Hyper-V resolver out of the picture, this doesn't happen.

While I can't test this directly at the moment, you should be able to either:

- Add `search foo.org` to your manually generated `/etc/resolv.conf`, since you already have the corporate nameservers in there
- Or add the Hyper-V switch address back in.  The challenge here is that that switch address changes each time WSL2 restarts, so you have to parse it and add it via scripting.  Something like:

  ```
  echo nameserver $(ip route show default | awk '{print $3}') | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
  ```

  Since this has to be done on each restart, you'll need some sort of singleton check to make sure it only gets added once per restart.

Comment: Adding `foo.org` to the top of `/etc/resolv.conf` fixed it.

Comment: If I wanted to test the automatically-generated `resolv.conf` ,what would I need to do?  Just rename the file `resolv.bak`?

Comment: @Craig That should work.  Just back-it-up/rename/move/etc. it so that it doesn't get overwritten, then comment out the `/etc/wsl.conf` line to let it auto-generate.  You'll need to `wsl --shutdown` to get it to auto-generate.  I seriously doubt the auto-gen one will work for you on AnyConnect, though.

Comment: The autogenerated `resolv.conf` added the same entry (`nameserver 172.29.80.1`) as the script that you suggested.

Comment: @Craig Right - I did expect that.  However, I didn't see your *AnyConnect* edit to the question until after I'd completed my answer.  A bit surprised that the Hyper-V switch/resolver is working when connected to AnyConnect, but if it is, then that's great!